# Google Chrome didn't shut down correctly

Tags: kubuntu, google-chrome, 17.10, shutdown, reboot

Everytime I either reboot or shutdown and later turn on my computer I get the message that *Chrome didn't shut down properly*.

I am using the reboot/shutdown from the Application Launcher (not cli). This persists on both Debian and flavors of Ubuntu. Currently I am running Kubuntu 17.10 (but the problem was also on Kubuntu 17.04). I have tried the following "workarounds", but they do not work.

1. Unselecting the *Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed*
2. Placing a script called `K99-close-google-chrome` (with `+x` permissions) in both the `/etc/rc0.d` and `/etc/rc6.d` folders

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   killall chrome
   sleep 5
   exit 0
   ```

I see posts dating all the way back to 2012 of this being an issue and none of them ever have a clear answer. Is there no fix for this problem and if so why? This isn't an issue on Windows or Mac, so why is it on Linux?

Comment: Could it be a problem with your profile? I don't have this issue with Google Chrome on Kubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @dk-bose I have one profile (and the guest). What could be wrong with my profile that is causing this issue?

Comment: Many of the files in the profile aren't plain text files and so understanding what could be wrong is difficult to say.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/979/ is probably very related to this problem. Especially considering this has been a problem since 2012 and this question still doesn't have an answer...

Comment: Have you tried closing Google Chrome directly before turning the PC off? :) I experienced the same problem only when I didn't close it.

Comment: I had this problem on Debian, for me #1 _did_ fix it

Answer (score 4):

I used this solution for Ubuntu 20.04.

Add this at the bottom of your `.bash_logout` file located in your home directory (If it does not exists create it).

```
pkill chrome
```

It will always close chrome properly whenever you shutdown or reboot.

Comment: Not working for me, Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this that might be the most simple:

Thanks to https://askubuntu.com/a/1335024 and some other googling, this is what I did. It seems to work on shutdown, reboot and logout.

1. Create a service file with your favourite editor:

   - `sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/kill-chrome-gracefully.service`

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Help Chrome close gracefully
   DefaultDependencies=no
   Before=shutdown.target

   [Service]
   Type=oneshot
   User=root
   Group= root
   ExecStart=killall chrome --wait

   [Install]
   WantedBy=halt.target reboot.target shutdown.target
   ```
2. Load it: `systemctl daemon-reload`
3. Enable it: `systemctl enable kill-chrome-gracefully.service`

This worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04 after repeated testing.
However, I am not 100% confident it will always work on logout.

**Bonus:** If you use `msedge`, or any other chromium based web browser, you can use the same and just changing the process name.

Answer (score 1):

I have Chrome in my startup programs and it always gives this error when I log in. I tried the [`pkill` setup](https://askubuntu.com/a/1362103/618353), but I still get the "Chrome didn't shutdown properly" error message.
I also tried removing Chrome from my startup programs, and just clicking on the icon after startup but got the same error message.

If I run the `pkill` script during my current session and then click on the Chrome icon, it starts with no error.

So then I followed these steps:

1. Ran `pkill` before shutting down.
2. Shut the computer down and then started again.
3. Clicked the Chrome icon.

This time Chrome started properly.