# How to run a command BEFORE shutdown on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: shutdown, reboot, restart, 21.04

I just want to run (as root) a command or script before each reboot/shutdown/poweroff on Ubuntu 21.04 (when I run the shutdown or poweroff commands, or using GNOME/KDE GUI options). I've tried putting the script inside `/etc/init.d` and making symlinks to `/etc/rc6.d/` and `/etc/rc0.d/` but doesn't work.

Wonder if there's such a line for `sudo crontab -e`.

Answer (score 11):

You can do this by creating a service file, then reloading `systemd`. Here's how:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Ensure the script that you want to run at shutdown is executable:

   ```
   chmod +x ~/scripts/pre-shutdown.sh
   ```
2. Create a file in `/etc/systemd/system` for the shutdown service. For the sake of this example, I'll call my file `nighty-night.service`.
3. Add the following lines to the `.service` file, modifying it as needed:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Pre-Shutdown Processes
   DefaultDependencies=no
   Before=shutdown.target
   # This works because it is installed in the target and will be
   #   executed before the target state is entered
   # Also consider kexec.target

   [Service]
   Type=oneshot
   ExecStart=/home/smeterlink/scripts/pre-shutdown.sh  # your path and filename

   [Install]
   WantedBy=halt.target reboot.target shutdown.target
   ```
4. Reload systemd, enable the service so it starts at boot time, then start it up:

   ```
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   sudo systemctl enable nighty-night.service
   sudo systemctl start nighty-night.service
   ```

You can see if it's running OK with `systemctl status nighty-night`

That's all there is to it.

Comment: My mistake it has to be ran as `root`. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, if you add the script to your `/etc/rc6.d/` directory with a name like `K99-preshutdown.sh`, then the script will run as `root` before the shutdown. (Note: scripts in `/etc/rc6.d` are executed alphabetically so, to have your script run *last*, give it a `K99` prefix.)

Comment: It does not work just putting the script there.

Comment: Step 5: enable the service: `sudo systemctl enable nighty-night`.