# Close chrome gracefully on shutdown

Tags: google-chrome, 22.04, shutdown, gdm

I've noticed that my chrome doesn't close gracefully on a shutdown. I've tried several things to solve it, but it's still an issue.

I found this command that works when running it manually: `killall -2 chrome --wait`.

An alternative one, based on many solutions found for Firefox:

```
if [[ -n `pidof chrome` ]];then
   echo "closing chrome..."
   WID=`xdotool search "Google Chrome" | head -1`
   xdotool windowactivate --sync $WID
   xdotool key --clearmodifiers alt+f x
fi
```

I've tried executing these commands in multiple ways:

- gdm3 PostSession
- /etc/rd0.d + /etc/rd1.d
- .bash_logout

PostSession and bash_logout don't seem to trigger on shutdown/reboot. And the etc script doesn't seem to work for chrome on shutdown.

Comment: Did you install chrome via snap or as deb?

Comment: "close gracefully on a shutdown" you mean, when you shutdown the computer without shutting down Chrome? How do you know it is not well closed? You appear to use 22.04. Are you in an xorg session? By default, you will be on Wayland, and xdotool does not work on Wayland.

Comment: @kanehekili It's an issue on both, first I had it installed through snap, reinstalling it as deb didn't solve it. Currently still on the deb version.

Comment: @vanadium Chrome opens with a notification that the session wasn't closed correctly, instead of correctly opening my previous tabs. And indeed shutting down the computer without closing Chrome manually. Pretty sure I'm on x11/xorg, but I'd except the killall command to work and the xdotool variant not being necessary.

Comment: Forgive me stating the obvious but why not just close chrome before shutting down so it can clean itself up?

Comment: @David While that works, I would prefer an actual solution. I would expect that shutting down the OS properly would tell every application to clean itself up instead of having it crash.

Comment: I'm struggling with this too, also on 22.04, this post didn't help https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002392/google-chrome-didnt-shut-down-correctly neither this one https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335022/how-to-run-a-command-before-shutdown-on-ubuntu-21-04 and neither https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208277/how-can-i-set-a-bash-logout-for-all-users